# Display (Sort by, compare product block) to the left ?

Tags: magento, compare, product

I use magento 1.7 and i wish to change the position of my sort by block and compare block to left.
what i will do that ?
thanks

Comment: will please give link or explain in little more detail

Answer (score 0):

in `catalog.xml`

remove this link from left

```
<reference name="right">
            <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

and add this to change it to left column

```
<reference name="left">
 <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>

</reference>
```

this will sure work in most of the pages of your magento site.